# package org.springframework.data.repository does not exist spring boot jpa

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a lil problem with spring boot + jpa. I have add the dependency to the POM.xml, i can run it normally from spring tool suite (run as spring boot application). But when i run from command line "mvn spring-boot:run" it will throws error.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building THA 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ THA >>>
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.1.RELEASE is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ THA ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ THA ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to D:\RondoWare\Programming\SpringBoot\workspace_3.8.3\THA\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /D:/RondoWare/Programming/SpringBoot/workspace_3.8.3/THA/src/main/java/com/rondox/sb/th/repository/ProductTypesRepository.java:[3,43] package org.springframework.data.repository does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/RondoWare/Programming/SpringBoot/workspace_3.8.3/THA/src/main/java/com/rondox/sb/th/repository/ProductTypesRepository.java:[7,49] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class CrudRepository
[ERROR] /D:/RondoWare/Programming/SpringBoot/workspace_3.8.3/THA/src/main/java/com/rondox/sb/th/controller/ProductTypeController.java:[29,39] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method save(com.rondox.sb.th.model.ProductTypes)
  location: variable productTypesRepository of type com.rondox.sb.th.repository.ProductTypesRepository
[ERROR] /D:/RondoWare/Programming/SpringBoot/workspace_3.8.3/THA/src/main/java/com/rondox/sb/th/controller/ProductTypeController.java:[36,46] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method findAll()
  location: variable productTypesRepository of type com.rondox.sb.th.repository.ProductTypesRepository
[INFO] 4 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.795 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-15T19:37:52+07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/267M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project THA: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /D:/RondoWare/Programming/SpringBoot/workspace_3.8.3/THA/src/main/java/com/rondox/sb/th/repository/ProductTypesRepository.java:[3,43] package org.springframework.data.repository does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/RondoWare/Programming/SpringBoot/workspace_3.8.3/THA/src/main/java/com/rondox/sb/th/repository/ProductTypesRepository.java:[7,49] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class CrudRepository
[ERROR] /D:/RondoWare/Programming/SpringBoot/workspace_3.8.3/THA/src/main/java/com/rondox/sb/th/controller/ProductTypeController.java:[29,39] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method save(com.rondox.sb.th.model.ProductTypes)
[ERROR]   location: variable productTypesRepository of type com.rondox.sb.th.repository.ProductTypesRepository
[ERROR] /D:/RondoWare/Programming/SpringBoot/workspace_3.8.3/THA/src/main/java/com/rondox/sb/th/controller/ProductTypeController.java:[36,46] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method findAll()
[ERROR]   location: variable productTypesRepository of type com.rondox.sb.th.repository.ProductTypesRepository
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.rondox.sb.th</groupId>
    <artifactId>THA</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>THA</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...) -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>            
        </dependency>

         <!---->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

my dependency tree :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building THA 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.1.RELEASE is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ THA ---
[INFO] com.rondox.sb.th:THA:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.24:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.24:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.24:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.24:compile
[INFO] |  \- nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.4.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.41:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO]    |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO]    |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO]    +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO]    +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.661 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-15T19:44:05+07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there any special parameter should i pass when i run the application from command line ? 
It's just simple application and the function is work as i expected when i run from STS, but i just want to have a better understanding if the STS & command line have difference parameter when run the application.

Answer (score 5):

you have to delete .m2 folder and change the version of dependencies and retry to update maven project.

Comment: No libraries found for 'org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository'

Comment: The location of the .m2 directory based on OS --> 
Windows: C:/Users/<UserName>/.m2
Linux: /home/<UserName>/.m2
Mac: /Users/<userName>/.m2

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had the dependency twice:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

After removing the second one, as I needed it outside of test, the errors disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

If someone has been experiencing problems with the Specifications class, it has changed.

Specifications is now Specification without the 'S'.

```
wrong:  import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specifications;
correct: import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.16</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is root cause of your problem:

> [WARNING] The POM for org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details

I think it come from your maven setting or java version in commandline.

Comment: could u be mo specific ? my java version "1.8.0_77" i have point the java_home to that jdk too. have tried googling with that dependency error but no luck.

Comment: You can re-run with full Debug mode
> Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Comment: i have run with -X but i cannot update that log here because it was very long. ok i have found out the issue.

Comment: Sorry i click enter, and it will post my comment. After i re-run with -X parameter i can see a clearer error message. It was caused by corrupted pom file. Once i also post question related to no class found error that turned out caused by corrupted jar. My question is how can i validate if my local maven repository is in perfect condition ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I re-run using maven command with -X parameters so it will turn on the debug logging.

Then the error got a clearer error message

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\RondoDell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\4.3.7.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.pom: processing instruction can not have PITarget with reserveld xml name (position: END_TAG seen ...</dependencies>\n</project>\n<?xml ... @108:7)  @ line 108, column 7

[WARNING] The POM for org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for org.jboss:jandex:2.0.0.Final
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\RondoDell\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jboss-parent\12\jboss-parent-12.pom: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not t (position: START_DOCUMENT seen t... @1:1)  @ C:\Users\RondoDell\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jboss-parent\12\jboss-parent-12.pom, line 1, column 1

[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.1.RELEASE is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.11.1.RELEASE
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\RondoDell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\build\spring-data-parent\1.9.1.RELEASE\spring-data-parent-1.9.1.RELEASE.pom: start tag not allowed in epilog but got s (position: END_TAG seen ...</pluginRepositories>\n\n</project>\n\t\t<s... @899:5)  @ C:\Users\RondoDell\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\build\spring-data-parent\1.9.1.RELEASE\spring-data-parent-1.9.1.RELEASE.pom, line 899, column 5
```

I delete the entire folder, run the application using command line, and it will redownload all pom and jar that needed. Application now can run normally from command line.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got a bad download of the following poms:

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.1.RELEASE is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
```

I've seen this happen when Maven ends up downloading an HTML error page instead of the artifact. You might try deleting your local Maven Repository at `~/.m2/repository` and then build from the command-line.

Answer (score 0):

sometime when you switch between two branch, you can meet this error. you just switch terminal tab in bottom IDE then run "mvn clean".